# Extract values from html tag and replace values with HTML tag text

Tags: javascript

I would like to extract values between tags that match a pattern. I want to then return a string where the text preceding the extracted value matches the text within the tag.

Here is an example to make this clearer. Assuming this is the string:

```
let testPattern = '<name>ladder</name><prx>112</prx><qty>12</qty>'
```

I would expect this as the outcome

```
name- ladder prx- 112 qty- 12
```

This is what I tried

```
var result = testPattern.match(/<[a-z]+>(.*?)<\/[a-z]+>/g).map(function(val){
    return val.replace(/<\/?[a-z]+>/g,'$1, $2')
})
```

This is my outcome

```
[ '$1, $2ladder$1, $2', '$1, $2112$1, $2', '$1, $212$1, $2' ]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is your inner regex, this should do the trick.

```js
const result = testPattern
    .match(/<[a-z]+>(.*?)<\/[a-z]+>/g)
    .map(val => val.replace(/<(\w+)\>(.*)\<\/\1\>/g,'$1 $2'))
```

Although maybe dividing it into an object could be a better option? Especially if you want to access the tag and the tag's contents separately. Perhaps something like:

```js
const testPattern = '<name>ladder</name><prx>112</prx><qty>12</qty>'
const regex = /<(\w+)\>(.*)\<\/\1\>/g

const result = testPattern
    .match(/<[a-z]+>(.*?)<\/[a-z]+>/g)
    .map((val) => ({ 
        tag: val.replace(regex, '$1'), 
        val: val.replace(regex, '$2') }))
```

Resulting in :

```js
[
  { tag: 'name', val: 'ladder' },
  { tag: 'prx', val: '112' },
  { tag: 'qty', val: '12' }
]
```